# How to display graphic of static 3D city in HTML?

Tags: html, css, 3d

I have never tried this before, I want to display a 3D city on top of a rectangle something like this.

[image]

Should I create this city from scratch using HTML on top of the rectangle? or can I just add a 3D image on top of the rectangle?

Here is my failed attempt at this.

here is my html

```
<div id="c" class="container">
 <div class="box r">
 <div class="side back"></div>
 <div class="side-vert left"></div>
 <div class="side-vert right"></div>
 <div class="side-hor top"></div>
 <div class="side-hor bottom"></div>
 <div class="side front">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YI1zImD.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
    $dim: 160px;
    $depth: 20px;
    $gap: 70px;

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
    }
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 100px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(25deg);
    }

    .box {
      cursor: pointer;
      position:absolute;
      width: $dim;
      height: $dim;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .side {
      border: 2px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      width: $dim;
      height: $dim;
    }

    .side-vert {
      border: 2px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      width: $depth;
      height: $dim;
    }

    .side-hor {
      border: 2px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      width: $dim;
      height: $depth;
    }


    .back {
      transform: translateZ(-$depth/2);
    }
    .left {
      transform: translateX(-$depth/2) rotateY(90deg);
    }
    .right {
      transform: translateX($dim - $depth/2) rotateY(90deg);
    }
    .top {
      transform: translateY(-$depth/2) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    .bottom {
      transform: translateY($dim - $depth/2) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    .front {
      transform: translateZ($depth/2);
    }

    .r {
      transform: translateZ($gap);
    }



    .r > * {
      background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2);
    }



    .vis > * {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/e0j4j5tz/1/

Comment: How or in what way do you consider your attempt failed? Because the fiddle logo is not standing upright on top of the rectangle? Do you want to be able to rotate the city by dragging afterwards?

Comment: @PatrickGünther I edited my fiddle(sorry abt the confusion) ..Now you can see I tried to screenshot part of apple maps 3d and rendered it on top of rectangle to see how it looks.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want with just a static image.

Comment: I see now. If you want to use the image you used in the fiddle you'd have to crop out a fitting region from the source image and make it slightly bigger than the `div.side.front` so that buildings overlap with the background on the top. If I had to do that and if the buildings don't have to be super detailed, I'd probably draw them dynamically on a 2D canvas.

Comment: Kind of like that: https://jsfiddle.net/qppfy9x3/